# Serializing IXmlSerializable Types Using XmlSerializer in WCF

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, xsd, xmlserializer, ixmlserializable

Thoroughly frustrated with the DataContractSerializer, I'm trying to get up and running in WCF using IXmlSerializable types with XmlSerializer.

I've implemented IXmlSerializable *and* XmlSchemaProvider in my class to be serialized and declared [XmlSerializerFormat] for my OperationContract.

Using a complex schema, I get the following error on trying to view the WSDL:

```
"Schema type information provided by IXmlSerializable is invalid: 
Reference to undeclared attribute group 'anAttributeGroupInMySchema'"
```

The schema has various includes (this attribute is declared in one of them). I even added the included schemas in code (`schema.Includes`) but to no avail.

Even in the most trivial example project (simple schema with 1 element and 2 attributes, simple corresponding class, you name it) I finally get past this error, but bump right into:

```
"WCF_IXmlSerializable.TestClass.TestSchemaProvider() must return a valid type 
name. Type 'TEST' cannot be found in the targetNamespace='www.test.com'."
```

Sadly I don't know what *is* a valid type name. It's certainly not an element name from my XSD, AFAICS.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Example source code can be viewed online [here](https://github.com/tomisbiginthegame/WCF_IXmlSerializable/tree/master/WCF_IXmlSerializable).

Comment: Could you post the code of the most trivial example?

Comment: Added to original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems: your test schema does not define a type named `TEST_CLASS`, it defines an element with that name. The XSD should be something like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="www.test.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="www.test.com">
  <xs:complexType name="TEST_CLASS">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="TEST">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="TYPE"/>
          <xs:attribute name="DURATION"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The second problem is that `XmlSchema` objects should be loaded using the`XmlSchema.Read()` method:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xsdDir + xsdFile)) {
  XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, null); 
  . . . 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight! I can't upvote on this account, but I would 100x! I sank a whole day into this... Another wonderful case of learning the hard way. This raises a number of other questions (topic for conversation elsewhere) but the most prominent seems relevant: is an XSD using the original declaration (root element, not complexType) considered invalid? I ask because A) XmlSpy reported a valid schema and B) I copied the format from a published schema I'm working with to replicate the error - it makes the same 'mistake'.

Comment: @TomTom: you're welcome. Your original schema was valid - the problem is that the `XmlSchemaProvider` machinery expects either a name of a complex type or directly a `XmlSchemaComplexType` object, and you were providing instead the name of an element definition.