# DataContractSerializer for custom Value types

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

I have a WCF service which exposes a type `TestTypeOne` which currently has a string property called `ProductId`:

```cs
public class TestTypeOne
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ProductId")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; } //note it's a string at the moment
}
```

I want to change the type of this property from `string` to a custom value type called  `ProductId`, but without breaking the WCF contract (this is only for the server side, the clients should see the `ProductId` as a string still.)

```cs
public class TestTypeOne
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ProductId")]
    public ProductId ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

The custom type is something like this (most code removed for brevity):

```cs
public struct ProductId : IEquatable<ProductId>
{
    readonly string productId;

    public ProductId(string productId)
    {
        this.productId = productId
    }

    public override string ToString() => productId ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Using the following test code:

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)))
{
    var dto = new TestTypeOne {
        ProductId = new ProductId("1234567890123")
    };

    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TestTypeOne));
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, dto);
    writer.Flush();
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

The expected output when serializing should be:

```xml
<Scratch.TestTypeOne xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Tests">
    <ProductId>1234567890123</ProductId>
</Scratch.TestTypeOne>
```

I have tried implementing `ISerializable` but that seems to only let me control the content of the `ProductId` xml tag, not the tag itself (so I can make things like `<ProductId><something>1234113</something></ProductId>` happen).

Ideally I am after something I can do to the `ProductId` type itself, as this type is used in many places, and many contracts.

Comment: And you need to deserialize this type too?

Comment: @Evk yes, but only on the server side still (so the clients should end up with a string property, only the server is doing the conversion to/from ProductId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think easiest way would be to implement `IXmlSerializable`:

```
public struct ProductId : IXmlSerializable
{
    readonly string productId;

    public ProductId(string productId)
    {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public override string ToString() => productId ?? string.Empty;

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() {
        return null;
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
        this = new ProductId(reader.ReadString());
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
        writer.WriteString(this.productId);
    }
}
```

To adjust WCF xsd generation for this case (force it to generate `xs:string`) - you can use data contract surrogate for xsd generation. For example you can have such suggorate:

```
public class ProductIdSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate {
    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type) {
        if (type == typeof(ProductId))
            return typeof(string);
        return type;
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType) {
        return null;
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType) {
        return null;
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, CodeCompileUnit compileUnit) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Whose only purpose is say that data contract for `ProductId` type is really `string`.

Then you can use this surrogate for schema generation:

```
var exporter = new XsdDataContractExporter();
exporter.Options = new ExportOptions();
exporter.Options.DataContractSurrogate = new ProductIdSurrogate();
exporter.Export(typeof(TestTypeOne));
```

You can use this approach for serialization itself, but I find it more complicated.

You can read more info about surrogates and WCF [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates), and the very bottom there is an example of how you can use surrogate for WSDL generation endpoint (section "To Use a surrogate for Metadata Export").

Comment: This is so close - the xml when serializing and deserializing is correct, and now I just need to figure out the wcf contract (which is now marking it as a value type, but still explicitly specifying the type, rather than using "xs:string")

Comment: @Pondidum I've added some info related to that.

Comment: that'll cover what I'm after - I think I'd looked into the surrogates at some point today, but apparently missed the useful part at the bottom.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Pondidum - You can also use [`[XmlSchemaProvider("MethodName")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlschemaproviderattribute.aspx) to get the correct schema.  See e.g. [WCF service xsd after IXmlSerializable implementation is not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38741035) or [Serializing IXmlSerializable Types Using XmlSerializer in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14989774) or [How can I control the root element namespace and name when serializing an IXmlSerializable object with the data contract serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47861220).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the DataContract/DataMember attributes to this ProductId class as well?

i.e:

```
[DataContract]
public struct ProductId : IEquatable<ProductId>
{

[DataMember]
readonly string productId;

public ProductId(string productId)
{
    this.productId = productId
}

public override string ToString() => productId ?? string.Empty;

}
```

Also, the name property (Name="ProductId") in this case is not needed, as the variable name is the same as the one you're overriding it with.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, that produces this in the xml: `<ProductId><productId>1234567890123</productId></ProductId>`, rather than the wanted `<ProductId>1234567890123</ProductId>`